# Help with Change back ($1, $5, $10, $20, Q, D, N, & Pennies)

Tags: math, vb6

Hey everyone, could anyone help me out with doing the Dollars in this function. It does the change just fine but it does **all** of the amount back in change and i want to big bills ($1,$5,$10, & $20)'s in dollars and the change in Q/D/N/P's.

```
Dim Quarters As Integer
Dim Dimes As Integer
Dim Nickels As Integer
Dim Pennies As Integer

Sub GetChange(ByVal Amount As Currency, ByRef Quarters As Integer, ByRef Dimes As Integer, ByRef Nickels As Integer, ByRef Pennies As Integer)
Dim Cents As Integer

   Cents = Amount * 100
   Quarters = Cents \ 25
   Cents = Cents Mod 25
   Dimes = Cents \ 10
   Cents = Cents Mod 10
   Nickels = Cents \ 5
   Pennies = Cents Mod 5

End Sub

Call GetChange(5.56, Quarters, Dimes, Nickels, Pennies)
```

Any help would be awesome! :o)

**Update, solved**

```
Private Sub theUSChange(Amount)
    Dim USCurrency(9) As Currency
    Dim USCurrencyNames(9) As Currency
    Dim Amount As Currency
    Dim Result As Currency
    Dim I As Integer

    USCurrencyNames(0) = " Pennies: "
    USCurrency(0) = 0.01
    USCurrencyNames(1) = "   Dimes: "
    USCurrency(1) = 0.05
    USCurrencyNames(2) = " Nickles: "
    USCurrency(2) = 0.1
    USCurrencyNames(3) = "Quarters: "
    USCurrency(3) = 0.25

    USCurrencyNames(4) = "      $1: "
    USCurrency(4) = 1
    USCurrencyNames(5) = "      $5: "
    USCurrency(5) = 5
    USCurrencyNames(6) = "     $10: "
    USCurrency(6) = 10
    USCurrencyNames(7) = "     $20: "
    USCurrency(7) = 20
    USCurrencyNames(8) = "     $50: "
    USCurrency(8) = 50
    USCurrencyNames(9) = "    $100: "
    USCurrency(9) = 100

    For I = UBound(USCurrency) To LBound(USCurrency) Step -1
        Do While Amount >= USCurrency(I)
            Amount = Amount - USCurrency(I)
            Result = Result + 1
        Loop
        Debug.Print(USCurrencyNames(I) & Result)
        Result = 0
    Next
End Sub

call theUSChange(5.77)

OUTPUT:
    $100: 0
     $50: 0
     $20: 0
     $10: 0
      $5: 1
      $1: 0
Quarters: 3
 Nickles: 0
   Dimes: 0
 Pennies: 2
```

David

Comment: This looks like homework. If it is, please tag it as such.

Comment: A quarter is to 25 cents as a dollar is to ________.

Comment: Just add values for your bills. You already have a start.

Comment: Its not homework, Marc. It's for a client of mine.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is worked out as an example in [Concrete Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201558025) using generating functions.

Comment: John, I believe you're thinking of the "how many ways to change a dollar problem".

Comment: You're right. It's not exactly the same problem, but it's entirely analogous.